Mutual Life Insurance Company of New York -- What is it now? How can I reach them?
My father recently passed away. Among his documents, I found an insurance policy issued by the Mutual Life Insurance Company of New York way back in the 1960s. I think that company became MONY.  But, MONY apparently no longer exists. I did some research online, and it seems they were bought by a French company named AXA.  But that leads me to a dead end. There is another company, Equitable, which claims to be the successor to MONY. But They do not recognize the policy number. A monthly debit is still being made on my father's checking account, listed as MONY.  Anybody have any idea how I can get in touch with MONY?

Can you have the bank trace the debit?

@littleadv: In practice, that is probably not very helpful. It will identify the corporate entity which is accepting the payment, and if you're very lucky, it might identify a specific subsidiary of a large conglomerate (or it might be something useless such as their Irish pass-through, which only exists for tax reasons and knows nothing about why they're charging you every month). You'll still have to figure out which part of the corporate bureaucracy to talk to, which is generally the hard part.

The OP was able to resolve it, but what I was thinking of was tracing the contact and reference I'd for the transaction

It turns out that Equitable is a subsidiary of the French company AXA. It took me several calls to Equitable, and several different representatives, but finally I got put through to the MONY division, who does have a record of the policy.

Excellent! It may go without saying, but don't forget to self-accept your answer tomorrow.

You may be able to get assistance from the state government. In the United Sates Insurance products are regulated to some level by the state government.
Start with the one where you father was living when the policy was first purchased. They should have an office that deals with insurance issues.
If money wasn't still being sent to the company for a policy, I would have said it is likely the policy lapsed.

Thank you for the good suggestion.  I was able to finally get in touch with MONY (see my own answer just posted).
